# Why does required attribute in html doesn't work?

Tags: html, forms, input, required

I wanted to try and verify input before being submitted therefore I used the required attribute at the end of input, but it's not working and I've already tried some of the recommended solution like wrapping the input in form tag or trying to close the tag of input () but when i submit my form with an empty input it stills submited normally and doesn't declare a required field .
I would appreciate any help, thank you!!
this is a part of my code

```
<form id="form" style="background-color:honeydew ;" class="container text-center">

    <div><br><h2> Contact Us </h2></div>
    <div id="contact">
        <div> 
            <label> Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name " name="name" required/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div> 
            <label> Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="name@gmail.com" name="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div> 
            <label> Message</label>
            <input type="text" style="height:50px;" name="message">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div><input type="button" value="submit" name="submit"><br></div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>

</form>
```

and this is the javascript file linked to it :

```
//we take informations subbmitted by user from the form and we replace the form with a reply
//containing these pieces of information on the click on the submit button
var form=document.getElementById('form'),
    contactForm=document.getElementById('contact'),
    submitButton=contactForm.children[6].children[0];

var processForm= function(){

    name=document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value,
    email=document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value,
    sitereplyText=document.createTextNode('this is a initialiazing value'),
    sitereplyEl=document.createElement('p');

    mytext= 'Hey '+name+'! Thanks for your message :)  We will email you back at '+email;
    sitereplyText.nodeValue=mytext;
    sitereplyEl.appendChild(sitereplyText);
    form.replaceChild(sitereplyEl,contactForm);
}


submitButton.addEventListener('click',processForm);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Is there any Javascript involved?

Comment: I am using Opera , yes there is a javascript page that I'm working on plus others linked to bootstrap for styling

Comment: So, is the form being submitted via Javascript?

Comment: yes it is by clicking on the sumbit button i call a function that takes the submitted information and proceed (submitButton.addEventListener('click',processForm);

Comment: Then you’re obviously replacing the form behavior with your own and need to replicate the required logic in Javascript too. Or instead of hooking the button click event, hook the form's `submit` event, which may only trigger after the validation (not sure off the top of my head right now).

Comment: Okey I'll try to work on what you've said, thank you for sharing !!

Comment: Write an answer for others when you got it.

Comment: Have you try with input type submit
<div><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br></div>

Comment: Yes that's what I did and it's working thank you

Answer (score 0):

So i firstly corrected the input type into submit

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

then in the javascript file i changed

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click',processForm);
```

to

```
submitButton.addEventListener('form.submit()',processForm);
```

and it seems to work :)